# Anonymous Scala function syntax

Tags: syntax, scala, anonymous-function

I'm learning more about Scala, and I'm having a little trouble understanding the example of anonymous functions in http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135. I've copied the entire code block below:

```
object CurryTest extends Application {
    def filter(xs: List[Int], p: Int => Boolean): List[Int] =
        if (xs.isEmpty) xs
        else if (p(xs.head)) xs.head :: filter(xs.tail, p)
        else filter(xs.tail, p)

    def modN(n: Int)(x: Int) = ((x % n) == 0)

    val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    println(filter(nums, modN(2)))
    println(filter(nums, modN(3)))
}
```

I'm confused with the application of the modN function

```
def modN(n: Int)(x: Int) = ((x % n) == 0)
```

In the example, it's called with one argument

```
modN(2) and modN(3)
```

What does the syntax of modN(n: Int)(x: Int) mean?

Since it's called with one argument, I'm assuming they're not both arguments, but I can't really figure out how the values from nums get used by the mod function.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a fun thing in functional programming called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Basically Moses Schönfinkel and latter Haskell Curry (Schonfinkeling would sound weird though...) came up with the idea that calling a function of multiple arguments, say `f(x,y)` is the same as the chain of calls `{g(x)}(y)` or `g(x)(y)` where `g` is a function that produces another function as its output.

As an example, take the function `f(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y`. A call to `f(2,3)` would produce `5`, as expected. But what happens when we curry this function - redefine it as `f(x:Int)(y: Int)`and call it as `f(2)(3)`. The first call, `f(2)` produces a function taking an integer `y` and adding `2` to it -> therefore `f(2)` has type `Int => Int` and is equivalent to the function `g(y) = 2 + y`. The second call `f(2)(3)` calls the newly produced function `g` with the argument `3`, therefore evaluating to `5`, as expected.

Another way to view it is by stepping through the reduction (functional programmers call this beta-reduction - it's like the functional way of stepping line by line) of the `f(2)(3)` call (note, the following is not really valid Scala syntax).

```
f(2)(3)         // Same as x => {y => x + y}
 | 
{y => 2 + y}(3) // The x in f gets replaced by 2
       |
     2 + 3      // The y gets replaced by 3
       |
       5
```

So, after all this talk, `f(x)(y)` can be viewed as just the following lambda expression `(x: Int) => {(y: Int) => x + y}` - which is valid Scala.

I hope this all makes sense - I tried to give a bit of a background of *why* the `modN(3)` call makes sense :)

Comment: Excellent explanation. I changed yours to the accepted answer (plus you fixed the error in the previous example).

Comment: Upvote for "Schonfinkeling" a parameter into a function. I'll only use this word from now on. :-D

Answer (score 3):

You are partially applying the ModN function. Partial function application is one of the main features of functional languages. For more information check out these articles on [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [Pointfree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-free_programming) style.

Answer (score 2):

In that example, modN *returns* a function that mods by the particular N.  It saves you from having to do this:

```
def mod2(x:Int): Boolean = (x%2) == 0
def mod3(x:Int): Boolean = (x%3) == 0
```

The two pairs of parens delimit where you can stop passing arguments to the method.  Of course, you can also just use a placeholder to achieve the same thing even when the method only has a single argument list.

```
def modN(n: Int, x: Int): Boolean = (x % n) == 0

val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(nums.filter(modN(2, _)))
println(nums.filter(modN(3, _)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. In this second example with the placeholder, can you explain what the last : Int is for, i.e.:
    def modN(n: Int)(x: Int): Int

vs
    def modN(n: Int)(x: Int)

Is that just syntax difference when a placeholder can be used and when it can't?

Comment: Also, I just tried that second example with the placeholder _, and the compiler complains that modN has the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: That's because `modN(x, y)` is not a valid way of calling the function (Scala does not do automatic uncurrying - i.e. transforming from `f(x)(y)` to `f(x, y)`). Therefore, the correct way to call `modN` in the example would be `modN(2)(_)`. Also, small nitpick - the return type of `modN` is incorrect, it should be `modN(n: Int)(x: Int): Boolean = (x % n) == 0`. Or you could let the type inferer infer it. :)

Comment: I updated the second example to be less wrong.  Thanks for the explanation Flaviu.